# angular bootstrap typeahead not working with a dynamic list retrieved by ng-change

Tags: angularjs, angular-bootstrap, angular-ui-typeahead

I am working with typeahead directive in angular-bootstrap. My problem is when user change the input, I want to trigger a ng-change event to get the list from the server, then filter the results. After that I want to see the list to be populated with uib-typeahead. For that, I am using an array $scope.list to store the result from the server and then I pass it into uib-typeahead as

```
 <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="asyncSelected" placeholder="Search city or zip code" 
    ng-change="getLocationForSearch(asyncSelected)" 
    uib-typeahead="item for item in list" />
 </div>
```

In the getLocationForSearch method, I update the list. I print the list in the console and it return correct value, however the list is not populated correctly in the dropdown. My plunkr is http://plnkr.co/edit/diot4RvsIdWht1zM3NeE?p=preview

Thanks

Comment: Could you please, share the whole <div> where the typeahead is located?

Comment: Hi @javier_el_bene, I updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as part of the typeahead directive without ng-change:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="asyncSelected" placeholder="Search city or zip code"
    uib-typeahead="item for item in getLocationForSearch($viewValue)" />
```

And then just return the list from the `getLocationForSearch` function. Here is a working plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/795euBYoCKxwzORoT2Hp?p=preview

Comment: Thanks @mahi-man, the reason I want to use an array instead of a promise is because I dont want to add an API call in a component. The UI component trigger an event to some controller when user type in sth, when that controller get the data it sends them back to my UI component and it is displayed in the drop down.

Comment: I think the problem in your setup is that typeahead creates it own scope, copying the data in your array, and when the array is updated by the async function, typeahead doesn't know about it so is always a step behind. I don't know how you can achieve what you want other than my original answer sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Add this directive to your `input`:

```
<input ... typeahead-on-select="onSelect($item, $model, $label)" />
```

Then remove `ng-change`

And finally, add `onSelect` function to your scope:

```
$scope.onSelect = function($item, $model, $label) {
    // do whatever you like
}
```

Comment: Thanks @nocodename, I removed the ng-change and then add the $watch function and call $scope.getLocationForSearch but it seems not working.

Comment: I've found another solution. Updated my original answer.  Hope it helps.

Comment: I am getting data from API, but when data come from api not updated in list? 
Can you suggest something?